# UseEffect dependency array keeps running even state does not change

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a useEffect which keeps running in a infinite loop even though my state, which i'm using in my dependecy array, are not changing(or am i missing something about my tasks-state that it is changing somewhere?)
The useEffect is used to query and retrieve data from Firestore, and here is the code:

```
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Animated } from 'react-native'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Subheading, Divider, Text, Modal, Button, Portal, TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { collection, where, query, getDocs, addDoc, deleteDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db} from '../../firebase/firebase'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import uuid from "react-native-uuid";


export default function TaskComponent({route}) {
  const item = route.params.item;
  const containerStyle = {backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 60, margin: 10};
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState({});
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState({name: "", description: ""});
  let userID = `${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid};`
  const filteredTasks = [];


  useEffect(() => {
    const getFilterTasks = async() => {
      const q = query(collection(db, 'allTasks'), where('userID', '==', userID), where('categoryID', '==', item.id))
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        filteredTasks.push(doc.data())
      })
      setTasks(filteredTasks)
    }

    getFilterTasks();

  }, [tasks])


  const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setTextInput({
      ...textInput,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };


  const showModal = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  }


  const hideModal = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  }


  const addTask = (textInput) => {
    setTasks((prevState) => {
      return [
        {
          userID: userID, 
          categoryID: item.id, 
          name: textInput.name, 
          description: textInput.description, 
          id: uuid.v1()
        },
        ...prevState
      ];
    })

    addToFirebase();

    hideModal();
  }


  const deleteItem = (item) => {
    setTasks((prevState) => {
      return prevState.filter(task => task.id != item.id)
    })
  }

  const addToFirebase = async() => {
      await addDoc(collection(db, 'allTasks'), {
        userID: userID, 
        categoryID: item.id, 
        name: textInput.name, 
        description: textInput.description, 
        id: uuid.v1()
      });
  }


  const DataComponent = (item) => {
    const rightSwipe = (progress, dragX) => {
      const scale = dragX.interpolate({
        inputRange: [-100, 0],
        outputRange: [1, 0],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
      });

      return(
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => deleteItem(item)}>
          <View>
            <Animated.Text>Delete</Animated.Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
      <Swipeable renderRightActions={rightSwipe}>
        <View>
        <View>
          <Text>Name:</Text>
          <Text> {item.name}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>Date:</Text>
          <Text> {item.date}</Text>
        </View>
          <Text>Description:</Text>
          <Text>{item.description}</Text>
        </View>
      </Swipeable>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Subheading>Your {item.name} tasks:</Subheading>
      <View>
          <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          data={tasks}
          renderItem={ ({item}) => (
            <DataComponent {...item}/>
            )}
            />
        </View>

        <View>
        <Button mode="contained" uppercase={false} onPress={showModal}>
          Add a task
        </Button>
      </View>

      <Portal>
        <Modal visible={visible} onDismiss={hideModal} contentContainerStyle={containerStyle}>
          <Text>Name your task: </Text>
          <TextInput placeholder="Enter task name" value={textInput.name} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('name', text)} name="name"/>
          
          <Text>Enter description:</Text>
          <TextInput multiline placeholder="Enter description" value={textInput.description} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('description', text)}  name="description"/>

          <Button mode="contained" uppercase={false} onPress={() => addTask(textInput)}>
            Add
          </Button>
        </Modal>
      </Portal>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I have also tried just with an empty dependency array, but then i have to refresh the code everytime i want to see the right data.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `tasks` from the triggers array.

Leave an empty array, so the `useEffect` will be called only at mount.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getFilterTasks = async() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'allTasks'), where('userID', '==', userID), where('categoryID', '==', item.id))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      filteredTasks.push(doc.data())
    })
    setTasks(filteredTasks)
  }

  getFilterTasks();

  }, [])
```

Comment: But i need to check run that code everytime the tasks state is changed, do you have any suggestion where i can put my setTasks(filteredTasks) or how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but inside the useEffect you are calling `getFilterTasks()` which is also calling `setTasks(filteredTasks)` which is basically changing your `tasks` object again and therefore triggers the `useEffect` again. This is the reason for your infinite loop.

What you want here is not an useEffect when you are adding, editing or removing a task, but rather a reusable function to call after the operation is complete to update the tasks. (an option would be getting the `getFilterTasks` function outside of useEffect and calling it after `await addDoc(collection(db, 'allTasks'), {...})`  inside your `const addToFirebase` function).